# Not able to insert elements into a set in c++

Tags: c++, stl, set

i have written a sample program.below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

std::set<std::string> m;
m.insert("1-2-1-1");

return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly without any errors.

But i try to create a set and try to insert elemts into it in my application code,it gives me the some  errors.

```
        /export/SunStudio/SUNWspro/bin/CC -c -compat=5 -features=no%altspell -features=no%export -mt +d  -DTHREAD -DSOLARIS -staticlib=rwtools7 -library=rwtools7,iostream -DOWTOOLKIT_WARNING_DISABLED -Bsymbolic -PIC  -g0 -DBPDEBUG  -I.  -I../nls  -I../../cnacore/api  -I../../cnacore/external  -I../../cnacore/stl  -I../../cnabp/kernel  -I/vobs/oss_design/sab/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/tbs/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/tss/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/tds/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/eam/inc  -I/vobs/ossrc_3pp/cif_3pp/borland_enterprise_server/include  -I/vobs/ossrc_3pp/cif_3pp/borland_enterprise_server/include/stubs  -I/vobs/ossrc_build_dependencies/extracted_packages/ERICsnlm/include  -I/vobs/ossrc_3pp/cif_3pp/sybase_ase/OCS-15_0/include  -I/vobs/cna/src/features  cacup_bsc.cc
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6545: Error: Multiple declaration for valid.
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6545: Error: "," expected instead of ".".
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6548: Error: Multiple declaration for valid.
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6548: Error: "," expected instead of ".".
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6552: Error: std::set_intersection<std::InputIterator1, std::InputIterator2, std::OutputIterator>(std::InputIterator1, std::InputIterator1, std::InputIterator2, std::InputIterator2, std::OutputIterator) is not a static data member.
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 6552: Error: Cannot use std::insert_iterator<std::set<std::string>> to initialize int.
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 8903: Warning: A non-POD object of type "bpDU" passed as a variable argument to function "std::sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)".
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 8906: Warning: A non-POD object of type "bpDU" passed as a variable argument to function "std::sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)".
6 Error(s) and 2 Warning(s) detected.
*** Error code 6
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "cacup_bsc.o"
```

below is the code that i have added.
but after commenting the below code.the compilation is successful

```
/*
std::set<std::string> valid;
valid.insert(string("1-1"));

std::set<std::string> planned;
valid.insert(string("1-1"));

std::set<std::string> result;

std::set_intersection(valid.begin(), valid.end(), planned.begin(), planned.end(), std::inserter(result, result.end()));
*/

        /export/SunStudio/SUNWspro/bin/CC -c -compat=5 -features=no%altspell -features=no%export -mt +d  -DTHREAD -DSOLARIS -staticlib=rwtools7 -library=rwtools7,iostream -DOWTOOLKIT_WARNING_DISABLED -Bsymbolic -PIC  -g0 -DBPDEBUG  -I.  -I../nls  -I../../cnacore/api  -I../../cnacore/external  -I../../cnacore/stl  -I../../cnabp/kernel  -I/vobs/oss_design/sab/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/tbs/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/tss/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/tds/inc  -I/vobs/oss_design/eam/inc  -I/vobs/ossrc_3pp/cif_3pp/borland_enterprise_server/include  -I/vobs/ossrc_3pp/cif_3pp/borland_enterprise_server/include/stubs  -I/vobs/ossrc_build_dependencies/extracted_packages/ERICsnlm/include  -I/vobs/ossrc_3pp/cif_3pp/sybase_ase/OCS-15_0/include  -I/vobs/cna/src/features  cacup_bsc.cc
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 8902: Warning: A non-POD object of type "bpDU" passed as a variable argument to function "std::sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)".
"cacup_bsc.cc", line 8905: Warning: A non-POD object of type "bpDU" passed as a variable argument to function "std::sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)".
2 Warning(s) detected.
```

below is the code that i have added:

```
std::set<std::string> valid;
valid.insert(string("1-1"));
```

could any one give me the right direction?

Below is the compilation flags:

```
/export/SunStudio/SUNWspro/bin/CC -c -compat=5 -features=no%altspell -features=no%export -mt +d  -DTHREAD -DSOLARIS -staticlib=rwtools7 -library=rwtools7,iostream -DOWTOOLKIT_WARNING_DISABLED -Bsymbolic -PIC  -g0 -DBPDEBUG
```

but for the sample program i am simply compiling like below:

```
/export/SunStudio/SUNWspro/bin/CC 0001.cc
```

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/kVV73) compiles, Show us your real code.

Comment: It will be relatively difficult to answer this question in it's current form. Are you able to pull together a minimal test case that we can run through a compiler that produces the error you are seeing?

Comment: @als.i know that this code really compiles when used directly .that is why i had to ask the question.i doubt may be the the way i am compiling is creating the problem.FYI,i have added the exactly same lines in between the existing code.I also pasted the compilation flags.

Comment: @peter: And yet you did not mention that in your Question or provide any relevant information that might help us know what you are trying to ask.If you wont ask We can only speculate.Please provide all information in questions you ask.

Comment: @als.. i am already speculated and that is why i had posted this here hoping to get some light .added some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have two variables in the same function that are named "valid".  Rename your new variable to `valid2` or change your code to just use a single variable named `valid`, with a single declaration.

You can NOT just write code like `valid.insert(string("1-1"));` unless it is inside a function.  In the comment below, you said it is not in a function.  You need to find some constructor of `std::set<std::string>` that has the same effect as calling `insert`.

Comment: Your file is AT LEAST 6544 lines long.  That's awful.  How long is the function you are debugging?  Maybe you are having trouble thinking of a name you didn't think of already?  Why don't you post the function?

Comment: I did not add the lines in a function.i added the lines just below the #includes.

Comment: Well that explains the problem.  See the second paragraph in my answer which I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have another declaration for `valid` in scope, hence the multiple declaration error.

Comment: NO i try to keep any name for it.its giving me the same error.